# Pyyaml - Python , omit !!int

Tags: python, yaml, tags, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

Is there a way to remove `!!int` after dumping to a yaml file?

Current output:

- "cores": !!int "4"
  "disks": !!int "200"

Expected:

- "cores": "4"
  "disks": "200"

Code:

```
Server = namedtuple("Server", "name ip mask gw vlan template cores sockets memory disks")
servers = []
for val in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2,min_col=2, values_only=True):
    server = Server(val[1],val[2],val[3],val[4],val[5],val[6],val[7],val[8],val[9],val[10])
    servers.append(server._asdict())

vms_spec = {}
vms_spec['vms'] = servers

with open('test.yml','w') as yamlW:
    yaml.safe_dump(vms_spec,yamlW,indent=2,default_style='"')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the `!!int` because you are dumping integers but force the output to be all double quoted scalars. Without that, a YAML parser reading the output would think it would need to load a string.

With that knowledge the easy solution is to walk over the values and convert them to a string before dumping:

```
servers.append({k, str(v) for k, v in server._asdict().items())
```

Please note that the [officially recommended extension](https://yaml.org/faq.html) for files containing YAML documents has been `.yaml` since at least September 2006.

Comment: Thanks,  worked , really forget this point.